# I'm trying to retrieve a string from a list in a file when I load with line.strip(''\n") its return me not full string if has dot

Tags: python, string, file

`users_db.txt` contains this data:

```
['ni.ght5460', 'padramukesh', 'theancientlight', 'i.am.ecoist', 'espacioukum', 'conciouscalling']
```

This is the code I tried:

```
with open('users_db.txt', 'r') as file:
     user = [line.strip('\n') for line in file]
```

Result:

```
'ni.g'
```

Comment: I don't see any line breaks in your `users_db.txt` file

Comment: I think users_db.txt must have something different in it. Can you print out the contents when you read it in?

Comment: I agree with jeffhale : you would expect a users_db.txt file with one entry per line and no quotes around names. Then you read that from python and put each entry in your user list, once the "\n" has been stripped.

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the format of the text file, there is no way to know how to put it into a data structure.

Assuming you have put the text file data into a list, here is how to get the items in the list that include a dot.

```
data = ['ni.ght5460', 'padramukesh', 'theancientlight', 'i.am.ecoist', 'espacioukum', 'conciouscalling']
data = [i for i in data if '.' in i]
```